# How do I tell whether EAX works in Uru: Complete Chronicles?

Tags: myst-series, uru-ages-beyond-myst

After following the guide in PCGamingWiki to enable EAX in Uru: Complete Chronicles (GOG edition) and adding DSOAL to the game folder I can still not hear any difference in game.

Since I've never played the game before I don't know exactly what effects to expect or where to expect it, but I was expecting some reverb on my footsteps while running around in the sandstone cave in the mushroom age.

**How can I tell for sure whether it works or not?** Is there a particular area (in early game) where I can expect e.g. reverb?

What I've done:

- [Installed the EAX fix](https://community.pcgamingwiki.com/files/file/2149-eax-fix-for-uru-complete-chroniclesages-beyond-myst/)
- Copied DSOAL's dsound.dll and dsoal-aldrv.dll to the game folder
- Also, before the above, installed the Official Beta Patch 1.1.4 which isn't directly related to audio (other than disabling DirectMusic)